# PHP: casting to a dynamically determined type

Tags: php, casting

I'd like do something like this:

```
$type = "int";
$casted = ($type)$value;
```

This doesn't work. But is there some other way to cast to a dynamically determined type?

Thanks

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the `settype()` function.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Example:

```
$type = 'int';
$var = '20';
settype($var, $type);
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Just happened to do the Google-Open-Copy-Paste process.

Comment: Amazing, came across this post via search this evening, and had to double take on your profile. Hope you're doing well since WSUK LDN 2011 :)

Comment: Please note that it's not useful to cast 'true' and 'false' to boolean. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php#107683